# Access-Control-Allow-Origin server side by php

Tags: php, javascript, tomcat, cross-domain

I am having problems with this topic: Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I read about it and I found that is possible to get response using php, [here](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/technotes/TN11.htm#getting)

But I don't know how to adapt that code to javascript, I still have the same problem.

I tried this in javascript:

```
var url ='http://localhost:8080/com.webserver/rest/manage/order?parameter=parameter';
req=Ajax("getResponse.php/?" + url)
  if (req.status=200)
alert("hi");
```

And on php file:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); 
?>
```

And nothing happends. I tried with ajax, something like:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8080/com.webserver/rest/manage/order?parameter=parameter",
          async: false,
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function (text) {
            alert(text);
          }
        });
```

But always same problem....

I read lot of people on internet having the same problem, but no one get a response. I just found 2 ways, using chrome and one option but just recomended for developers and adding headers on server but I don't know where to add them. I am using apache tomcat catalina for that localhost. I have 2 servers, webpage (in xampp) and rest (in tomcat)

Comment: Where do you set, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and where would you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`req=Ajax("getResponse.php/?" + url)`

to

`req=Ajax("getResponse.php/?url=" + url)`

Bare in mind this is insecure, i could pass anything into the url parameter and your php scripts would use it. Allowing people to read files from your local system as well as get your php script to download malicious files from elsewhere

Edit:

To best way to secure it is to use an actions list, this means that the user never see's the url and can only modify an action word. for example

`req=Ajax("getResponse.php/?do=getOrders")`

then in php

```
$actions = array();
$actions['getOrders'] = "http://localhost:8080/com.webserver/rest/manage/order?parameter=parameter";

if(array_key_exists($_GET['do'], $actions))
 echo file_get_contents($actions[$_GET['do']]);
```

Usually you'd want to do more that just translate an action to a url, you may want to pass additional parameters. In this case you could use a switch or a bunch of IF's to check if $_GET['do'] is equal to something and then process it. but it would take hours to give an example of every possible implementation method, so you may want to use google.

Please note: whilst this method is suggest adds 100x more security to your script, its not infallable, especially if you start passing through parameters from users too. Once again use google.

Comment: God... Now it gives me an error about Ajax is not defined.... Is there a way to make it secure? I can change all parameters in server... Just allowing some address or something like that.

Comment: Ajax is not defined is probably because you dont have the library included which implements that object/function. Personally i stick with jQuery, but if you've done a lot of code under that library already or jQuery is not suitable you'll have to stick with it.

I'll add an edit to my post on how to secure it

Comment: With Jquery, it would be as I wrote upper, won't it? $.ajax.... Now it is working, thanks a lot! I receive what I want.